# Application of the uniform boundedness principle

Tags: functional-analysis

I have the following corollary, but I'm not sure about the final step.

Assuming $Z$ to be a normed space, let $B\subseteq Z$ such that: $\forall f \in Z^*: \sup_{z\in B}\mid f(z)\mid<\infty$ then $\sup_{z\in B}\mid\mid z\mid\mid< \infty$

Proof:

Since $Z$ is a normed space, $Z^*$ is a Banach space.
So I consider $\tau\subseteq\mathcal{L}(Z^*,\mathbb{K})$. Using the isometry-map $i:Z\longrightarrow Z^{**}, z\mapsto i(z)$ I can identify the subset $B\subseteq Z$ with $i(B)\subseteq Z^{**}$.

Now I aim to use the uniform boundness principle, so I have to check: $\forall x\in Z^*:\sup_{T\in \tau}\mid\mid Tx\mid\mid<\infty$.

Now the final step is to bring the supremum in the assumption in the last form and here I am not so sure...

$\sup_{z\in B}\mid f(z)\mid=\sup_{z\in B}\mid <f,z>_{Z^*,Z}\mid=\sup_{i(z)\in i(B)}\mid <f,i(z)>_{Z^*,Z^{**}}\mid=\sup_{T\in \tau} \left| <T,z>_{Z^{**},Z^*}\right|=\sup_{T\in \tau}\mid Tx\mid$

Is this way correct?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is correct.

Alternatively, $Z$ has a completion $\tilde Z$ (which is of course a Banach space), and $\tilde Z^*$ is isometric to $Z^*$ - in fact,
$$
Z^* = \big\{\varphi\lvert_Z : \varphi\in \tilde Z^*\big\}.
$$
Then simply use the UBP for $B\subset \tilde Z$.